Do Alaska MVP members still board in Group B if you purchase the Saver fare?
Alaska's boarding rules say that MVP passengers board in Group B. They also say that Saver fare passengers board in Group F. Which rule will take precedence if an MVP passengers buys the Saver fare?
I've recently reached MVP status so haven't had a chance to try it out.

Side note: I only care about the boarding group due to a couple of horrible experiences with getting my luggage in JFK. Otherwise it obviously doesn't matter.

Boarding will be according to your elite status:

As an elite Mileage Plan member, what benefits do I receive on a Saver fare?

You may board according to your status. Baggage fees are still waived according to your status, and you'll receive the same refreshments and inflight entertainment. Existing elite bonuses apply.

Note: All other Saver rules and restrictions apply. Saver fare cancel, change, or refund policies apply for all elites who purchase a Saver fare.

Source
